# How to test a method with XCTestCase in Objective C which does not return a value

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, xctestcase

I am practicing for Unit test cases in XCode. I have a method in my controller class which has some lines of code but this method does not return any value. So my confusion is how can I write a test case function for this type of method. Below is my method for which I need to write the test case function. Can anybody please help me understand how to do this? Thanks in advance.

```
    _Bool isValid = true;
_strUserEmailEdited = @"Abc@test.com";
_strPasswordEdited  = @"123456789";

if ([_strPasswordEdited isEqualToString:@""] || [_strUserEmailEdited isEqualToString:@""]){
    if ([_strPasswordEdited isEqualToString:@""]) {
        _lblErrorPassword.text = @"Password is required.";
    }else{
        _lblErrorEmail.text = @"Email is required.";
    }
    isValid = false;
}

if ([_strPasswordEdited isEqualToString:@""] && [_strUserEmailEdited isEqualToString:@""]){
    NSLog(@"Please,Enter values");
    _lblErrorPassword.text = @"Password is required.";
    _lblErrorEmail.text = @"Email is required.";
    isValid = false;
}
else {
    // Validation check for EmailId
    if ([_strUserEmailEdited length]==0){
        _lblErrorEmail.text = @"Email is required.";
        isValid = false;
    }
    else if (!_strUserEmailEdited.isValidEmail) {
        // Check for Valid EmailId
        _lblErrorEmail.text = @"Please enter a valid email address.";
        isValid = false;
    }
    else if (_strUserEmailEdited.isValidPassword){
        _lblErrorEmail.text = @"";
        isValid = true;
        _lblErrorEmail.text = @"";
    }
    // Check for Valid Password
    if ([_strPasswordEdited length]==0){
        _lblErrorPassword.text = @"Password is required.";
        isValid = false;
    }else if (!_strUserEmailEdited.isValidPassword) {
        isValid = false;
        _lblErrorPassword.text = @"";
    }else if([_strPasswordEdited length]>=1 && _strUserEmailEdited.isValidEmail){
        _lblErrorPassword.text = @"";
        isValid = true;
    }else{
        isValid = false;
        _lblErrorPassword.text = @"";
    }
}
if (isValid==true){
}
```

Comment: What are the things you care about? ...the resulting values of `_lblErrorPassword.text` and `_lblErrorEmail.text`?  Where are they defined?

Comment: It looks like you are always changing your `isValid` variable in each of these methods. Why not re-write the methods to return a `BOOL` instead. Then you can test if the correct `BOOL` is being returned. Sometimes writing unit tests means re-writing code to make it easier to test.